# Excel - Change old comments to new Threaded comments

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm tired of comments going all over the place, and cauzing scroll bar to shrink, so I wanted to build a macro to convert all old Notes to new Threaded Comments. The problem I ran into is that I need to keep the original Author, but when I try to change the author of my Threaded Comment, I get an errror, see code below.

How can I change the author for Threaded comments? Google has not shown me the way :)

```
Public Sub Convert_Notes_to_Comments()
    
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim CommentText As String, cleanedText As String, commentAuthor, newComment As CommentThreaded
    Set rng = Selection
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            CommentText = cell.Comment.Text
            commentAuthor = cell.Comment.Author
            cleanedText = Replace(CommentText, commentAuthor & ":", "")
            cell.Comment.Delete
            Set newComment = cell.AddCommentThreaded(cleanedText)
            cell.CommentThreaded.Author = commentAuthor   'I GET AN ERROR HERE
        End If

    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: [Author](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentthreaded.author) property is read-only. Idea - Perhaps change your [UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.username) to `commentAuthor` before `AddCommentThreaded`?

Comment: Application.username did not work unfortunatelly. I will try with Environ("username")

Comment: Do you want changing the comments for a specific range (selection), or all of them (in a specific sheet, or in all workbook)?

Comment: I'm afraid that `CommentThreaded.Author` is read Only. It is automatically placed when the comment is done. It cannot be changed as you want... You may use a trick. Do not replace anything and simple use `AddCommentThreaded(CommentText)` and it will keep the former user of the former user. Do you use Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `CommentThreaded.Author` is a `read-Only` property. Excel automatically add the new user. If you use Excel 365 (like I suppose), the chosen user is not the Windows user account, it is the Microsoft logging one...

Please, try the next code. It will do what you try doing. Beside that, it keeps the former user name, if it is different against the actual (used) one:

```
Sub changeOldCommentsInThC()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, rngComm As Range, commentAuthor As String, cleanedText As String
  Dim cel As Range, CommentText As String, newComment As CommentThreaded
  
      Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
      On Error Resume Next 'if no comment existing it will raise an error
         Set rngComm = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments) 'all comments on the sheet
      On Error GoTo 0
      If Not rngComm Is Nothing Then               'if there are (old) comments:
            For Each cel In rngComm.cells          'iterate between range cells
                CommentText = cel.Comment.text     'memorize the comment text
                commentAuthor = cel.Comment.Author 'memorize the comment author
                cel.Comment.Delete                 'delete the comment
                cleanedText = Replace(CommentText, commentAuthor & ":" & vbLf, "") 'remove the former user
                Set newComment = cel.AddCommentThreaded(cleanedText)                'create the Threaded comment
                If commentAuthor <> newComment.Author.Name Then 'if not the author of both comments is the same:
                    cel.CommentThreaded.Delete     'delete the newly created threaded comment
                    Set newComment = cel.AddCommentThreaded("Former user: " & CommentText) 'recreate it keeping the former user name
               End If
            Next
      End If
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. It can be easily adapted to change all old comments for all sheets in the workbook...

Comment: @Dumitru Daniel Did you find some time to test the above suggestion? If tested, didn't it clarify the issue? Just curious... :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb. Excel has built in functionality to convert old comments to new threaed comments, keping the author. And this is good, because I did not find any other solution that worked, as the Author field in the threaded comments is read-only.
[image]